# Missing rows in MyISAM tables with 10-20 billion records

Tags: mysql, myisam, tokudb

I've got 2 tables with 10-20 billion records each.

Currently these are in MyISAM (MySQL).
They only require to be built and indexed once, after this only SELECT is used.
They are currently partitioned into 100 partions each.
MyISAM is currently used because it has lower storage, has fast SELECT and supports `LOAD DATA INFILE`, `REPAIR WITH X THREADS` (for index building) and supports having the data & index files in a different directory from default (which is required because the file sizes are too large for the partition that the rest of MySQL runs on, which is an SSD.)

This is on a single server with single quad-core i7 processor and 64GB RAM, running CentOS 6.

The table structure is:

```
id bigint(20) UNSIGNED
word1 mediumint(8) UNSIGNED
word2 mediumint(8) UNSIGNED
origyear smallint(5) UNSIGNED
cat tinyint(3) UNSIGNED
pibn int(10) UNSIGNED
page smallint(5) UNSIGNED
pos smallint(5) UNSIGNED
num tinyint(3) UNSIGNED
```

The indexes are:
(Note that the primary key is over id & word1 as the partitioning is done over word1 and it is required to be part of the primary key to be used as the partitioning value.)

```
PRIMARY id, word1
INDEX word2, word1, pibn
INDEX origyear, word1
INDEX cat, origyear
INDEX pibn, word1
INDEX pibn, page, word2
INDEX word1, word2, num, pibn, page
```

The problem is that half of the rows are missing after importing. I can confirm that the rows exist and have unique keys as I have checked this in the flat files that the tables are built from (when they were first imported with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.) Luckily I have a backup of these flat files so it would not be difficult to reimport the entire tables (except that it takes about a month to import and index it all.)

I have no idea why these rows are missing, I guess it's just because MyISAM can't keep up with the amount of data.

I need advise on how to fix this, or a better storage engine that can be easily migrated to without having to change all the code in the scripts that use this data (all the SELECT statements.)

These tables are used in combination with other MyISAM & InnoDB tables in some SELECT statements, so it is necessary that they are part of an SQL database supporting that.

I've been looking at TokuDB but I'm not sure if it will be better. Plus is not does appear to support having the data in a different directory to default, which is required since I have only 300GB of SSD and these 2 tables are obviously several TB in size.

Comment: Nothing... someone must have an idea?

Comment: You still have your chances with TokuDB: although, as you suggest, it does not support splitting files across different direcotries, it does have excellent compression ratio (I met with x20 compression factor on ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_SMALL) which means it may yet fit in your SSD

Comment: Are always the same records missing from the import if you retry or are the missing records random?

Comment: Always the same records are missing and they are missing in groups, like several thousand records that were next to each other in the insertion file will always be missing.

Comment: I agree with that was mentioned in the comments, the compression of TokuDB will make the tables much smaller on-disk.  One question, if the tables are several TB in size, then how are you fitting them on a 300GB device with MyISAM?

Comment: Did it throw any errors/warning(skipped rows) while you where trying to LOAD DATA? If there was some warnings, what was that?

Comment: @cjg I don't know, that was a long time ago and I don't have those logs anymore.

Comment: @tmcallaghan, those tables are on a different drive for this reason.

Comment: Then with TokuDB you'll have to pick one file system to hold it all.

Comment: Could you specify which version of mysql you experienced this issue with? I ask because we faced a similar issue with a later version (5.6.19) but it did not seem to occur with an earlier version (5.6.12, though it might have been an earlier version). Alternatively, have you tried partially loading the table with data to narrow down at what size the problem can be reproduced?